# How do I show that $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ is the cube root of 1?

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

Actually I don't even know where to start... like someone told me to cube my 2... then Id get a 8. But I don't get any smarter on this problem by cubing it.

$ (1+\sqrt[2]{3i}) /2))$
What should I think about?

(I'm sorry this will be my last question without LaTeX.)

Comment: Why don't you just cube it?

Comment: You should ask how to show that it is **a** cube root of 1.

Comment: could u elaborate on that... should i cube the numerator and denomiator... or just 2? 

What would I achieve with that... Im so confused

Comment: @Amir Do you understand what it means for a number, say $x$ to be a cube root of $1$? Can you write using mathematical symbols?

Comment: ahh.... ok, now im stuck... what is a cube root of 1.

ok, i googled it... it is 1. because of 1^3 is 1. 

ok, so i should show that is an equation with ending up the result of 1... am i getting that right?

Comment: You seem to be closer now than you were before. To say that a number $x$ is a cube root of $1$ is to say that $x^3 = 1$. You said that $1$ is a cube root of $1$ because $1^3 = 1$. That's exactly right.

Comment: x to be a cube root of 1... x=1 bc cube root of 1 is 1 again... 

but below that there is an answer with saying... cubing the binomial... i dont see any binomial. xD Could someone tell me how to spot that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Euler's formula, if you wish to avoid cubing the binomial. Notice that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}&= -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
&= \cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3} \\
&=e^\frac{2 \pi i}{3}
\end{align}
$$

And then you have

$$\left(e^\frac{2 \pi i}{3}\right)^3=e^{2 \pi i}=\left(e^{ \pi i}\right)^2=(-1)^2=1$$

Comment: Thanks, but just one question... where do you spot the binomial?

Comment: This answer explicitly avoids the binomial expansion. @Amir

Comment: I know... but hold up... binomial expansion. That's new stuff to me.

Comment: Are you self learning?  If so, then you may be trying to learn things not in a "standard" sequence.  In almost every algebra class, learning to expand binomials using FOIL usually comes before complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, I’m studying on my own. Kind of weird, when it comes to problems. I’ll study way more algebra.

Answer (score 2):

$\left( \dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) \left( \dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) \left( \dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)$

Multiply the first two together using FOIL. Their product is $\left( \dfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)$

Now multiply this by the third factor $\left( \dfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) \left( \dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)$ and it comes out $1$.